# How to run Javascript in php class member function

Tags: javascript, php

I have a class which is having a static function named save

```
if ($subid = $vpl->add_submission( $userid, $files, $comments, $errormessage )) {
    $id = $vpl->get_course_module()->id;
    \mod_vpl\event\submission_uploaded::log( array (
            'objectid' => $subid,
            'context' => $vpl->get_context(),
            'relateduserid' => ($USER->id != $userid ? $userid : null)
    ) );
} else {
    echo "<script>alert('hello');</script>";
    throw new Exception( get_string( 'notsaved', VPL ) . ': ' . $errormessage );
}
```

It's giving me a parse error.

Comment: Would you post the "parse error" ?

Comment: I am working in Moodle so it's just throwing a popup showing connection fail: parse error

Comment: In your first line do you mean `$subid = $vpl...`, or should that be `$subid == $vpl...`?

Comment: That's all right no problem in that